# Qlearning and indexing of reward

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

my question might be easy, but I am not sure about time indexes in well known Q-learning equation.

The equation: 
Qt+1(St, At) = Qt(St, At) + alpha * (Rt+1 + gamma * max_A(Qt(St+1, A)) - Qt(St, At))

and I don't understand what Rt+1 stands for. Simple example:

1. We are at state X at time T.
2. pick new action based on epsilon-greedy
3. apply action
4. We are at state Y at time T + 1
5. (now we want update Q values for state Y) reward is calculated from action X -> Y (?) or is it reward from action Y -> Z after evaluating all next Q-values (max_A(Q(Y, A)))
6. repeat 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the previous turn you were in state s(t) and took action a(t). Now you are in state s(t+1), receive reward r(t+1) and (greedily) choose action a(t+1). You adjust the value of the previous action towards the sum of the discounted value of the new action and the reward.

A few misconceptions in your example:

1. you are actually updating action, not state values
2. you are updating values for the action at state X, not Y
3. the specific action taken at state X may lead to various states, not just Y, so there is no such thing as the X→Y action

Comment: OK just one question. When updating Q(s, a), I take max_A Q(s', A) (and then pick greedily action form s'), right?

Comment: @SnurkaBill `a(t+1) = max_A(s(t+1), A)` is the greedy choice of action

Comment: OK I see where is problem now, my implementation with finite state space worked well, but when I want to generalize it by some classifier (neural nets) I am getting in trouble and nothing works. Could you please help me with this topic?

Comment: @SnurkaBill That's a bit too much, sorry. :)